# Use random number (arc4random_uniform) to display random shapes

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, random

The purpose for this code is to do random number to display random shapes but the simulator displays them in the same spot which is the bottom left corner of the screen, for some reason the random for the position which is `a` is not working.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import Darwin

class StartGame: SKScene {

var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "cholkDuster")
var square = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square")
var circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")
var rectangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle")
var triangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "triangle")
let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
var score = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    //random number for the shapes

    var timecreatShapes = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("creatShapes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    //background image

    bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    bg.size.width = self.frame.size.width
    bg.size.height = self.frame.size.height
    self.addChild(bg)

    self.scoreLabel.text = "0"
    self.scoreLabel.fontSize = 42
    self.scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 2

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.5)

    //declaring a square image

    square.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    square.color = SKColor.redColor()
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    square.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    square.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    //declaring a circle image

    circle.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    circle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    //declaring a triangle

    triangle.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    triangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    triangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    //declaring rectangle

    rectangle.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
    rectangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: square.size.height / 2)
    rectangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    rectangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

}

func creatShapes () {

    var x = Int ( arc4random_uniform(4) + 1)
    var a = CGFloat ( arc4random_uniform(1000) + 1)

    switch(x){
    case 1:
        circle.position = CGPoint (x:  a , y: self.frame.size.height)
        self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"circle"))
    case 2:
        square.position = CGPoint(x:  a , y: self.frame.size.height)
        self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"square"))
    case 3:
        rectangle.position = CGPoint(x:  a , y: self.frame.size.height)
        self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"rectangle"))
    case 4:
        triangle.position = CGPoint(x: a , y: self.frame.size.height)
        self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"triangle"))

    default:
        break

    }
    println(x)
    println(a)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
       if (self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.square || self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.triangle || self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.circle || self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.rectangle){

        self.score++

        }
        self.scoreLabel.text = String(self.score)
    }

}
```

Comment: It might help to read the *first* line of the exception message.

Comment: @nhgrif  i did read it but i cant quite figure out what to do here , i am kinda new at swift

Comment: @nhgrif never mind i fixed it by changing the self.addChild(shape) ---- self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"shape"))

but i came across another error , i edited the post , could you please take a look at it

Comment: Change it back and post the exception. You're setting `circle` position (`StartGame` class property), but later you're not adding `circle`, but you're adding new `SKSpriteNode` (`SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"circle")`), which has nothing to do with your `circle` property (where position was set).

Comment: @robertvojta  when i change the skspritenode(imagenamed: "circle") , it works fine but it only displays one of each image and then it crashes